# Why type constraint in a generic class is not enough for the compiler when implementing an interface?

Tags: c#, generics

If the type constraint guarantees that T implements IParameter, why cannot I implement IMain's Method with T as an argument?

```
interface IMain
{
    void Method(IParameter parameter);
}

interface IParameter
{
}

class Implementation<T> : IMain where T : IParameter
{
    //public void Method(IParameter parameter) { }//accepted implementation
    public void Method(T parameter) { }//leaves the class with a "does not implement member..." compiler error
}
```

Comment: "_If the type constraint guarantees that T **implements IParameter**_" That is correct. But you seem to draw the wrong conclusion that therefore T must be `IParameter`. But in reality, any other type **implementing IParameter** is allowed for `T` as well. As an example, despite List<T> implementing IEnumerable<T>, a method signature `void Foo(List<T> stuff)` is not the same as `void Foo(IEnumerable<T> stuff)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the type constraint guarantees that T implements IParameter, why cannot I implement IMain's Method with T as an argument?

Let's assume for a second that that's legal and see what happens in this scenario.

Suppose, we have two classes that implement `IParameter`:

```
class Param1 : IParameter { }
class Param2 : IParameter { }
```

Then, we create the following object:

```
var p1 = new Implementation<Param1>();
```

At this point, `p1.Method` would only take an argument of type `Param1`. So, attempting to do something like this won't work:

```
p1.Method(new Param2());  // This is illegal, as expected.
```

Now, let's cast `p1` to `IMain` and try again:

```
var asIMain = (IMain)p1;
asIMain.Method(new Param2()); // What should happen here?!
```

On one hand, we have `IMain` whose `Method` takes an `IParameter` argument, so it should allow a `Param2` object. But on the other hand, the underlying type of `asIMain` is `Implementation<Param1>` whose `Method` only accepts a `Param1` argument. The compiler is smart enough to prevent this situation from happening.